# Spring MVC resources - how to map file(s)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a better way to control how paths are mapped using Spring MVC?

At the moment I have:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/*-application.js" location="/resources/"/>
```

And this would make it so that any request to a file of the form *-application.js will be searched for in /resources/. But what I really want to do is something along these lines:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/*-application.js" location="/resources/application.js"/>
```

Is this possible? How do you do it?